# Сервер не отвечает на EPP HELLO

Tags: xml, dns

Мне нужно работать с регистратором зоны .NL — sidn.nl.

У них сервера EPP. Я беру стандартный шаблон EPP HELLO, добавляю 4 байта (размер сообщения в big endian) через CURL — в ответ сервер не дает вообще никакого ответа. Вот как готовлю всё:

```
var epp_hello = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'+
    '<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">'+
    '    <hello/>'+
    '</epp>'; // шаблон
var xml = bigEndian(epp_hello)+""; // big endian
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, "drs.domain-registry.nl"); // 
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.PORT, 700); 
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POST, 1);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HEADER, true);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POSTFIELDS, xml);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HTTPHEADER , ['Content-type: text/xml']);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.TIMEOUT , 180);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);   
curl.perform();
```

В ответ не получаю вообще ничего — ни заголовка, ни данных.

IP в панели управления прописан абсолютно точно. 
Их техподдержка прислала мне линк на мануал, в котором описан в общем EPP и сказала

> Met vriendelijke groet :-)

**UPDATE:** Спасибо Mike за подсказку, curl действительно нельзя использовать. Как-то если XML, то значит HTTP, по привычке — но здесь с особым пристрастием подход...

Тем не менее, переделка на TCP пока ничем не помогла:

```
var epp_hello = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'+
                '<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"><hello/></epp>'; 
var xml = bigEndian(epp_hello); 

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(700, "drs.domain-registry.nl", function(xxml) {
    console.log('Connected ', xxml);
    client.write(xxml);
}.bind(null,xml));

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

От сервера никакие данные не приходят.

Comment: Не знаю, что это у вас за язык, но bigEndian от текста всей xml выглядит странно. было бы логично если бы функция с таким названием байты в нужном порядке расставляла для числового аргумента, а уж никак не для текста

Comment: bigEndian это моя функция

Comment: function bigEndian(xml) {
    var xmlBuffer = new Buffer(xml);

    var xmlLength = xmlBuffer.length;
    var endianLength = xmlLength + 4;
    var b = new Buffer(4);
    b.writeUInt32BE(endianLength, 0);
    var preppedXML = Buffer.concat([b, xmlBuffer]);
    return preppedXML;
};

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете ? В RFC на протокол EPP ни про какую длину ни слова. curl этого так же не требует

Comment: В их мануале это написано - любой xml должен начинаться с 4 байтов длины сообщения, включая сами эти 4 байта. Но я пробовал и без длины

Comment: @Mike язык javascript, node.js

Comment: ну вы бы этот мануал показали. или вы думаете, что тут найдутся специалисты работавшие с тем регистратором ? Вообще в RFC EPP ни слова ни сказано, что это HTTP протокол. А раз так то curl для его реализации в принципе пользоваться нельзя

Comment: да и 4 байта длины как бы намекают, что этот протокол должен идти в виде сырого TCP. Ибо в HTTP не принято кодировать так какие либо длины, ибо HTTP текстовый протокол

Comment: он у них в интранете, но вот закинул на GD - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YTWfVKjv7_alhkemNaRTlSSXM/view?usp=sharing 
Я вообще надеялся что проблемы с EPP типовые и кто-то может сталкивался с подобным где угодно еще

Comment: хм.. да, я curl взял по привычке как самое сподручное... блин xml по tcp посылать это вообще уже изыски садамаза ...

Comment: ща возьмусь за сокеты - спасибо Вам за конструктивный чат :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119111/how-do-you-connect-to-an-epp-server-domain-registry-in-node-js

Comment: да, я уже на этом пути - спасибо огромное, дальше сам разберусь - TCP была ключевая подсказка, а я туплю к сожалению :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос разрешился при использовании tls вместо net:

```
const epp_hello = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'+
                '<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"><hello/></epp>'; 

const opts = {
};
var xml = bigEndian(epp_hello); 
var client = tls.connect(700, "drs.domain-registry.nl", opts, function(xxml) {
    client.write(xxml);
}.bind(null,xml));

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});
```

Получил EPP GREETING